# Complete Error correction code with length n on q letters.

Tags: combinatorics, gray-code

$C$ is an complete e-Code for error correction with length $n$ on a set of $q$ letters.

I want to compute the length of $C$ set.

Comment: There are usually multiple possible $C$'s; do you mean you wanted the longest possible length of such a $C$? If so, this is an open problem, and you will need to be less demanding if you want an answer.

Comment: what about shortest?

Comment: The shortest possible length is trivially one.